# Python noob question. Looping through all to find correct combination

Tags: python

Sorry for noob question. Just started learning coding with Python - beginners level.
Wasn't able to find in the net what I require.
Creating function to loop through the entire line, in order to find right combination - 7,8,9 - regardless of input length and of target position, and return 'true' if found. Wasn't able to devise the function correctly. Not sure how to devise function clearly and at all this far.
Your help is much appreciated.
This is what I came up with so far (not working of course):

```
def _11(n):
    for loop in range(len(n)):
        if n[loop]==[7,8,9]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
print(_11([1000,10,11,34,67,89,334,5567,6534,765,2,3,5,6,112,7,8,9,11111]))
```

It always returns False. Tried with (*n) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The answer offered by @Carson is entirely correct.

I offer this not really as an answer to the question but as an alternative and more efficient approach.

In OP's question he is looking for an occurrence of 3 consecutive values described by way of a list. Let's call that a triplet.

If we iterate over the input list one element at a time we create lots of triplets before comparing them.

However, we can make this more efficient by searching the input list for any occurrence of the first item in the target triplet. In that way we are likely to slice the input list far less often.

Here are two implementations with timings...

```
from timeit import timeit

def _11(n, t):
    offset = 0
    lt = len(t)
    m = len(n) - lt
    while offset < m:
        try:
            offset += n[offset:].index(t[0])
            if n[offset:offset+lt] == t:
                return True
            offset += 1
        except ValueError:
            break
    return False

def _11a(n, t):
    for index in range(len(n) - len(t)):
        if n[index:index + len(t)] == t:
            return True
    return False

n = [1000,10,11,34,67,89,334,5567,6534,765,2,3,5,6,112,7,8,9,11111]
t = [7, 8, 9]

for func in _11, _11a:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(lambda: func(n, t)))
```

**Output:**

```
_11 0.43439731000012216
_11a 1.8685798310000337
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the str representation of the 2 lists:

```
import re

def _11(n):
    if re.search("(?<![0-9-.'])7, 8, 9(?![0-9.])",str(n)):
        return True
    return False

print(_11([27,8,9]))
```

The Output:

```
False
```

Comment: This will fail for the array `[27, 8, 9]`

Comment: U mean pass that array?

Comment: yes. `_11([27, 8, 9])` will return true, but it should return false

Comment: good point, maybe a regex approach would be better

Comment: fixed it with a regex approach

Comment: this example will still fail for inputs like `[7, 8, 99]`. You should add regex checks to the other side as well!

Comment: Also, to be extra annoying, if you input an array which contains strings you can also make it fail. `_11(['7, 8, 9', 'other text', 'stuff'])`

Comment: I think the current iteration solves all the aforementioned problems

Comment: @Carson Before strings, I'd worry about I integers. For example `[-7,8,9]`, where this code says `True`.

Comment: lol fixed that as well

Comment: Also decimals, e.g.: `[0.7, 8, 9]`

Comment: and decimal suffxies, `[7, 8, 9.2]`

Comment: lol add to the regex as u need for your usecase... I will fix that too

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes with your code.

Indexing into a loop returns 1 element, not multiple. When you write `n[loop]`, you're getting 1 value, not a list.

You shouldn't return false that early. Your code exits after the first step in the loop, but it should go through the entire loop before returning false.

Consider the following snippet:

```
def has_subarr(arr, subarr):
    """Tests if `subarr` exists in arr"""
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i:i+len(subarr)] == subarr:
            return True
    return False
```

This code is more general than your example, it accepts the value to check for as another argument. Notice the use of `:` in the array access. This allows you to return multiple elements in an array. Also notice how the `return False` is only reached once the entire loop has completed.

Answer (score 0):

First, n[loop] return a single element, not a sublist. You should use n[loop+3]. But this will introduce a problem where loop+3 exceeds the length of the list. So the solution may be:

```
def _11(n):
    for loop in range(len(n)-3):
        if n[loop:loop+3]==[7,8,9]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
print(_11([1000,10,11,34,67,89,334,5567,6534,765,2,3,5,6,112,7,8,9,11111]))
```

Your actual code return during the first iteration. You only test once. You must modify the indentation as in:

```
def _11(n):
    target = [7,8,9]
    for index in range( len(n) - len(target)):
        if n[index:index + len(target)] == [7,8,9]:
            return True
    return False
print(_11([1000,10,11,34,67,89,334,5567,6534,765,2,3,5,6,112,7,8,9,11111]))
```